# Frequency of particle in magnetic field

Tags: special-relativity, magnetic-fields

For motion in uniform magnetic field we have 2 parameters that give us trajectory. Radius and frequency. Formulas for them are:

\begin{equation}
r = \frac{p_{\perp}}{0.3B\cdot e}
\end{equation}
Where $p_{\perp}$ in GeV, B in Teslas and e in elementary charges.
\begin{equation}
\omega = \frac{c\cdot e\cdot B}{E}
\end{equation}
Note that formula for frequency depends on full energy of particle but radius depend on transvere momentum.

I have 2 questions:

1. Why there is dependence on full energy for frequency and not only on transverse part
2. What shoudl be units in second formula? c in m\s, B in Teslas, E/e in GeV?